Using ARIMAX correctly in R
I am working with the R programming language. I have data on crop yield and fertilizer costs. I want to make a time series model (ARIMAX) that predicts crop yield based on (crop yield -1, crop yield -2) and (fertilizer costs -1, fertilizer costs -2). Then, I want to predict the next 12 months of crop yields assuming that fertilizer cost remains constant at  $1000 each month (during this next 12 months) ... but I am struggling to understand how to correctly use ARIMAX in R.
Step 1: First, I simulated data for this problem
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

custom_lag <- function(x, n) {
  c(rep(NA, n), x[1:(length(x) - n)])
}

set.seed(123)
n <- 100
dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = n)
fertilizer <- runif(n, 500, 1500)
crop_yield <- 0.5 * fertilizer + arima.sim(list(ar = c(0.7, 0.2)), n) + rnorm(n, 0, 50)

data <- data.frame(
  date = dates,
  crop_yield = crop_yield,
  fertilizer = fertilizer
)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    lag1_crop_yield = custom_lag(crop_yield, 1),
    lag2_crop_yield = custom_lag(crop_yield, 2),
    lag1_fertilizer = custom_lag(fertilizer, 1),
    lag2_fertilizer = custom_lag(fertilizer, 2)
  ) %>%
  na.omit() 

Step 2: Then, I fit the model:
model <- auto.arima(ts(data$crop_yield, frequency = 12), 
                    xreg = cbind(data$lag1_crop_yield, data$lag2_crop_yield,
                                 data$lag1_fertilizer, data$lag2_fertilizer, data$fertilizer),
                    max.p = 0, max.q = 0, max.d = 0) 

Step 3: Then, I made a vector to represent the future fertilizer cost as a vector:
future_dates <- seq(from = max(dates) + 30, by = "month", length.out = 12)
future_fertilizer <- rep(1000, 12)


future_regressors <- matrix(0, nrow = 12, ncol = 5)
future_regressors[, 5] <- future_fertilizer  # Current fertilizer
future_regressors[1, 1:2] <- tail(data$crop_yield, 2)  # Initial lagged crop_yield
future_regressors[1, 3:4] <- tail(data$fertilizer, 2)  # Initial lagged fertilizer

Step 4: This part was difficult for me, but I had to then perform the forecasts sequentially and place everything into a single data frame:
forecast_result <- forecast(model, xreg = future_regressors, h = 12)

for (i in 2:12) {
  future_regressors[i, 1:2] <- future_regressors[i-1, 1:2]
  future_regressors[i, 1] <- forecast_result$mean[i-1]
  future_regressors[i, 3:4] <- future_regressors[i-1, 3:4]
  future_regressors[i, 3] <- future_fertilizer[i-1]
}

forecast_result <- forecast(model, xreg = future_regressors, h = 12)

historical_data <- data %>%
  select(date, crop_yield, fertilizer) %>%
  mutate(type = "Historical")

forecast_data <- data.frame(
  date = future_dates,
  crop_yield = as.numeric(forecast_result$mean),
  fertilizer = future_fertilizer,
  type = "Forecast"
)

combined_data <- bind_rows(historical_data, forecast_data)

Step 5: I then tried to make a plot of the forecasts
ggplot(combined_data, aes(x = date, y = crop_yield, color = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data = forecast_data, 
              aes(ymin = as.numeric(forecast_result$lower[, 2]), 
                  ymax = as.numeric(forecast_result$upper[, 2]), 
                  fill = type), 
              alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Historical" = "black", "Forecast" = "blue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Historical" = NA, "Forecast" = "lightblue")) +
  labs(title = "crop_yield Forecast",
       x = "Date",
       y = "crop_yield",
       color = "Data Type",
       fill = "Forecast Interval") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

This took me a lot of time and was very convoluted. Is there an easier way to use the ARIMAX model without so many helper functions?
